# How sync data to a SQL server in multi-tenant setup from local sqlite

Tags: sqlite, postgresql, ios4, synchronization, conflict

I have a scenario where N clients connect to a central server (PostGres based). All of the N clients can get offline, and store everything in sqlite database. Is a service like fresh books, to make invoices.

Each client have a local copy of the main data (customers, products) filtered for that user. All client can update customers, products and each one work for their own invoices (i.e.: each client edit only his own invoices, but see aggregated data for everyone).

I know about add timestamp and GUID IDs, but not how approach this task. About how detect conflicts and auto-solve it, or if exist a sample code I can look about this..

P.D: Only sqlite is fixed. Because I'm in the planning stage, I could switch to any tech necessary that could solve better this task... I'm work with .net, python, django, obj-c

Answer (score 1):

have a look at Sync Framework. although in your case, you may have to write a custom provider to work with the non-MS databases.

here's a sample using PostGres: [InfoQ: Making Microsoft Sync Framework work with PostgreSql.](http://www.infoq.com/articles/Microsoft-Sync-Framework-PostgreSql)

some links to Sync Framework to give you an idea how it works:

[Synchronizing SQL Server and SQL Express](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928676%28SQL.110%29.aspx)

[How to: Handle Data Conflicts and Errors for Database Synchronization (SQL Server)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc761628%28SQL.110%29.aspx)

[Synchronizing Other ADO.NET Compatible Databases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc807291%28SQL.110%29.aspx)

[Offline-Only Scenarios](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb902819%28SQL.110%29.aspx)

[How to: Use a Custom Change Tracking System](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc305973%28SQL.110%29.aspx)